# How to find the length of mp3 file in golang?

Tags: go, mp3

I have an .mp3 file stored on the hard drive. How can I find its length in seconds using go language?

I've found 2 go libraries that are about mp3:

- https://godoc.org/github.com/hajimehoshi/go-mp3
- https://github.com/tcolgate/mp3

But there are no working examples how to get the mp3 file length in seconds.

Answer (score 6):

You can calculate the duration of each frame and sum them to find the total duration.

Here is the example of this (`https://github.com/tcolgate/mp3`) library to find the duration:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"

    "github.com/tcolgate/mp3"
)

func main() {
    t := 0.0

    r, err := os.Open("<mp3 file path>")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    d := mp3.NewDecoder(r)
    var f mp3.Frame
    skipped := 0

    for {

        if err := d.Decode(&f, &skipped); err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        t = t + f.Duration().Seconds()
    }

    fmt.Println(t)
}
```