# How to get the duration of an mp3 file in Golang?

Tags: go, audio, text-to-speech, openai-api, openai-whisper

I set up a text to speech an request that to openAI API then it generates an audio. Now I want to know it's duration in [MM:SS], is there a way or a library to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered here:

[How to find the length of mp3 file in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281655/how-to-find-the-length-of-mp3-file-in-golang)

Also, you would want to transform a float64 in MM:SS format. In this case you can use something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/tcolgate/mp3"
)

const mp3File = <path-to-mp3-file>

func main() {
    var t float64

    fd, err := os.Open(mp3File)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer fd.Close()

    d := mp3.NewDecoder(fd)
    var f mp3.Frame
    skipped := 0

    for {

        if err := d.Decode(&f, &skipped); err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        t = t + f.Duration().Seconds()
    }

    fmt.Println(t)

    // Convert the value to a time.Duration object
    duration := time.Duration(t * float64(time.Second))

    // Get the duration in minutes and seconds
    minutes := int(duration.Minutes())
    seconds := int(duration.Seconds()) - (minutes * 60)

    // Format the duration in the MM:SS format
    formatted_duration := fmt.Sprintf("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)

    fmt.Printf("The value %v expressed in MM:SS format is %v.\n", t, formatted_duration)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [go-audio library](https://github.com/go-audio/audio)

From there, you can seek the last frame from the file

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/go-audio/audio"
)

func main() {
    filePath := "....mp3"
    file, _ := os.Open(filePath)
    decoder := audio.NewDecoder(file, filePath)
    _ = decoder.SeekLastFrame()
    duration := decoder.Duration()
    fmt.Printf("Duration of %s: %v\n", filePath, duration)
}
```

Comment: I get an error that NewDecoder is not available

Comment: Didn't really realize, seems the decoder is now here: https://github.com/go-audio/aiff/blob/master/decoder.go

Comment: it cannot decode the mp3 file. It returns 0s even though the file is 1:30 mins

Comment: does the file have any specific format or encoding? For me it works quite fine, did you seeklastframe?

Comment: It doesn't have seeklastframe function. the file is flac mp3

Comment: seems that the seeklastframe doesn't even matter, the decoder has an attribute called duration, which is calculated quite nicely:

func (d *Decoder) Duration() (time.Duration, error) {
 if d == nil {
  return 0, errors.New("can't calculate the duration of a nil pointer")
 }
 d.ReadInfo()
 if err := d.Err(); err != nil {
  return 0, err
 }
 duration := time.Duration(float64(d.NumSampleFrames) / float64(d.SampleRate) * float64(time.Second))
 return duration, nil
}

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/tcolgate/mp3"
)

func Duration(mp3FilePath string) (string, error) {
    file, err := os.Open(mp3FilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer file.Close()

    decoder := mp3.NewDecoder(file)
    totalDuration := 0.0

    var frame mp3.Frame
    var skipped int
    for {
        if err := decoder.Decode(&frame, &skipped); err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            return "", err
        }
        totalDuration += frame.Duration().Seconds()
    }

    duration := time.Second * time.Duration(totalDuration)
    return fmt.Sprintf("[%02d:%02d]", int(duration.Minutes()), int(duration.Seconds())%60), nil
}

func main() {
    path := "path/of/your/mp3/file"
    duration, err := Duration(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(duration)
}
```

[image: ffprobe output]

[image: golang output]